# Google Dialogflow V2 webhook not working - InvalidType and Null Exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es

I'm following google example to create a .net core 3.0 webhook for dialogflow using Google Dailog Flow cersion 2 api.  this is the code

```
public class DialogflowController : ControllerBase
{
   private static readonly JsonParser jsonParser =
        new JsonParser(JsonParser.Settings.Default.WithIgnoreUnknownFields(true));

    public ContentResult DialogAction()
    {
        WebhookRequest request;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
        {
            request = jsonParser.Parse<WebhookRequest>(reader);
        }

        // Note: you should authenticate the request here.

        // Populate the response
        WebhookResponse response = new WebhookResponse
        {
            // ...
        };

        string responseJson = response.ToString();
        return Content(responseJson, "application/json");
    }
}
```

I'm using SoapUI to create a rest service and test the code using a post request copied from dialogflow itself.  When running I'm receiving the following error:

```
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.ContextReflection' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'extension')
```

Any ideas why or what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My project is on .NET Core 3.1 at the moment, and I had to make a change to the code to asynchronously read from the StreamReader. I had to change this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
{
     request = jsonParser.Parse<WebhookRequest>(reader);
}
```

With this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
{
     request = jsonParser.Parse<WebhookRequest>(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
}
```

I also had to update the method signature with the async keyword and put the ContentResult in a Task.

public async Task DialogAction()

Hope this help